# Visual with 3 related tables 1 to N with different behavior

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In the example below, the pop up displays all tags, not tags related to the highlighted card.

In the example above, the visualization comes out correct, however, it is mandatory to add a field from the Cartes_Etiquetas table in the visualization, so that it is displayed correctly filtered.

With the relationships being correct, how do I filter the data correctly, WITHOUT ADDING THE MIDDLE COLUMN IN THE VIEW?

Link to files on exemple...
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eA8-DObEqnZNOInNehaO9UIlliO-SkPu?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new measure as follows:

```
Measure = COUNTROWS('Cartões_Etiquetas')
```

Add the measure to the filter pane as follows:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I knew it should be something simple, but I couldn't think outside the box :)